# File system issue when running Spark Java application on AWS EMR

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm developing a Big Data application using Spark in Java. The application uses Amazon S3 services where the dataset (.gz files) is stored. I finished developing the code locally on my laptop by using one file of the dataset and I'm trying to run it on Amazon EMR on all the files of the dataset. But the problem is it can't get the files on the FileSystem from Amazon S3.  I tried using:

```
   hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
   hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", myAccessKey)
   hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", mySecretKey)
```

and the path:

```
     S3://accessKey:secertKey@path
```

and the error was:

> ```
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591) at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91) 
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630) 
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612) at 
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370) at 
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296) at 
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputForma‌​t.java:256)
> ```

Comment: would you please add the exception ninto your question, not in a comment?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more concise. I also included your comment in the body, properly indented - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional code samples and detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help